# Using Karate Robot DSL for Windows desktop apps written in Swing and Mac OS support

Tags: java, swing, karate

- For those that have used Karate robot for automating desktop applications in Windows written in Swing I'm curious to know what your experience was like? i.e. were the test runs reliable or flaky?
- What was the best spy object tool you used to help identify Swing components and feed that to Karate scripts?
- Also I see that https://github.com/intuit/karate/projects/3 MacOS support is in the backlog, is there any update on whether this update will support Swing apps on MacOS?

Appreciate your support, thanks.

Comment: This could be closed on the basis of either Opinion-based *or* Needs more focus. I chose to vote for the latter. Please [edit] the question to remove the first two parts ('opinion based') and focus only on the 3rd. Comments like *"Appreciate your support, thanks."* should also be removed. They add no information, are 'chatty' & do not increase the chance of getting answers.

Comment: agree with closing as `needs more focus`, added an answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson for the clarification. I'll make sure to keep that in mind next time i ask a question here.

Answer (score 2):

Developer of Karate Robot here. Most known users are targeting Windows MFC / C++ / .NET or Delphi so there are no reports of Swing yet, but my guess is that it should work at least on Windows. "inspect.exe" works well to introspect the component tree. And we are looking for contributions for Mac, but there doesn't seem to be much interest - yet.

To summarize, I think your best bet is to contribute code to Karate, and you can make that decision based on your comfort with Java and your evaluation of how good Karate is in its current state and if it will "stay around", mature into a good desktop testing tool etc.

Comment: plus one for comment here

Comment: Thanks @Peter for your response. Will take a further look into Karate code and report back if i have any further questions.